# I can't push items into jasvacript array quick enough

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, performance, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI slider that when a user triggers a slide function, I need to push the current slide value into an array. The problem is, when a user slides the handle too quickly, the length of the array and the current index value fall out of sync. As if the array cant update as quick as the user can slide...

Is there a solution for this?

Thanks.

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
     max: gCoordsArray.length,
     min: 0,
     step: 1,
     slide: function(event, ui){

           var direction = '';

           // test whether we are sliding left or right ( increasing / decreasing increment )

           if (ui.value > count) direction = 'right';
           if (ui.value < count) direction = 'left';

           count = ui.value;

           if (direction == 'right') {                            
                test.push(count);                                
                console.log(test.length); // Should match count
                console.log(count); // Should match length
           }

           if (direction === 'left') {
                test.pop();
                console.log(test.length); // Should match count
                console.log(count); // Should match length
           }                                    

     }, 1)

});
```

Comment: Wait until the user releases the control of the slider to push the value?

Comment: It's possible that the slider isn't reporting an event for every incremental change, so there are gaps in the count being reported. For example, it starts at 2 and the user slides very quickly to 8. You may only get events for 2, 5 and 8, so you end up with an array length of 3 and a count of 8. Why do you need an array `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`, anyway? If that's absolutely required, you might want to consider generating the range between the value when they start sliding and the value when they stop sliding rather than using an event handler.

Comment: limelights - Unfortunately that won't work for this scenario. I am drawing a Google map polyline which is controlled by the slider, therefore I need it to update on the slide event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test.length` and `count=ui.value` won't be the same except in the edge-case that the user only moves one step at a time.

The [slide event](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide) returns the current mouse position, if the user skips straight to the end, `ui.value` will be `gCoordsArray.length` while `test.length == 0`

One solution might be to record in a "global" var (outside the event handler) the previous position and compare that, eg:

```
var prevPosition = 0;

$( "#slider" ).slider({
    max: gCoordsArray.length,
    min: 0,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {

        var thisPosition = ui.value;

        if (thisPosition > prevPosition) direction = 'right';
        if (thisPosition < prevPosition) direction = 'left';

        if (direction == 'right')
        {
            while (prevPosition != thisPosition) 
            {
                prevPosition++;
                test.push(prevPosition);
            }
        }
        ... equivalent for left
     }, 1)
});
```